# What is the point of doing bitwise shifting here?

Tags: c++, c, io, bitwise-operators

I found this code for fast I/O.

```
    #include <cstdio>

inline void fastRead_int(int &x) {
    register int c = getchar_unlocked();
    x = 0;
    int neg = 0;

    for(; ((c<48 || c>57) && c != '-'); c = getchar_unlocked());

    if(c=='-') {
        neg = 1;
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    }

    for(; c>47 && c<58 ; c = getchar_unlocked()) {
        x = (x<<1) + (x<<3) + c - 48;
    }

    if(neg)
        x = -x;
}

inline void fastRead_string(char *str)
{
    register char c = 0;
    register int i = 0;

    while (c < 33)
        c = getchar_unlocked();

    while (c != '\n') {
        str[i] = c;
        c = getchar_unlocked();
        i = i + 1;
    }

    str[i] = '\0';
}

int main()
{

  int n;
  char s[100];

  fastRead_int(n);
    printf("%d\n", n);

  fastRead_string(s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

Why is there a bitwise shift (x<<1) + (x<<3)? Also what's happening when we enter character other than neg and numbers?

Comment: Without any context of what's going on or what the function is doing, it's difficult to know what those bitwise operations are doing. If it's of any help, a one bit left shift is the same as multiplying by 2 and a three bit left shift is the same as multiplying by 8.

Comment: I have added the complete code. Here is the blogpost: http://digital-madness.in/blog/2013/fast-io-in-c/#comment-2137 Basically this method is used in competitive programming for faster i/o.

Comment: `(x<<1) + (x<<3)` equals multiplying by `10`. If you take a decimal representation of a number, that a "left shit"(ex: `12 * 10 = 120`). `c - 48` adds the new digit at the end.

Comment: Isn't it simply doing a multiply by 10 (8x + 2x = 10x)? I'd bet a compiler could do that optimization if it's beneficial.

Comment: Consider a simple input of two values. `'2'` and `'3'`. Starting with `x=0`, the first pass does nothing but store `2` in `x`. The second pass will add `3` to the value `(2<<1 + 2<<3)`, which is `(4+16) + 3` or `(20) + 3`. I.e. 23. In other words, this is multiplying the previous value by `10` and adding the next char as a decimal single digit afterward.

Comment: <<1 = 2 + <<3 = 8 = 10, so it's multiplying x by 10.

Comment: @FredLarson - I've certainly come across compilers that don't do the optimization, and it is often worth doing, particularly on embedded platforms that don't have an integral multiply instruction.

Comment: This is a case of micro-optimization.  Most of the time for I/O lies outside of your program, such as waiting for the user to type in a number or reading a number from a file.  Parsing the data in memory is magnitudes faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is there a bitwise shift (x<<1) + (x<<3)?

A left shift by `n` bits is equivalent to multiplying by `2^n`; so this expression is equivalent to multiplying by ten (since `2^1 + 2^3 = 2 + 8 = 10`).

The code is written like this in the belief that (a) shifts and adds are significantly faster than multiplication, and (b) the compiler doesn't know the best way to multiply by ten. Both these assumptions are wrong for most modern platforms, so the straightforward

```
x = x*10 + c - '0';    // '0' is more readable, and portable, than 48.
```

is likely to be faster as well as more readable.

> Also what's happening when we enter character other than neg and numbers?

The first loop skips over anything other than '-' and digits; the second stops when a non-digit is encountered (AFTER consuming that character from the stream). So it will return the first decimal integer it finds in the input stream, or zero if there is none. For example, if the input is

```
xxxx123-456xxx-1234xxx
```

The first call will return `123`, the second `456` (since the `-` was consumed by the first call), the third `-1234`, and any further calls `0`.

Comment: Everybody thinks they're smarter than the compiler.

Comment: Good spot on its consumption of one additional character.  (One could add that it's not checking for overflow either, something vital when reading input.)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even notice the extra consumption. The algorithm itself had be reaching for my coffee with extra vigor. nice catch.

Answer (score 5):

This is really bad code.  For starters, why 48 and 57, rather
than `'0'` and '`9'`.  And with regards to your questions: the
bitwise shifts are used for obfuscation, and possibly to slow
things down.  The expression `(x << 1) + (x << 3)` has the same
mathematical value as `10 * x`.  It's just a lot less readable,
and can interfere with some compiler optimizations.  (On
processors where the two shifts and the addition are faster than
the multiplication, the compiler will to the transformation for
you, generally better than if you write it out, because it knows
why it is shifting.)  And as for your second question: the code
in question will skip ahead ignoring all characters until it
finds a digit or a minus sign; it will convert something like
`"abc12"` to `12`, without the slightest error.

In fact, it is the total absence of error checking (and the use
of `getchar_unlocked`, rather than `getchar`) which makes it
fast.

Comment: +1 to you and Mike. The posted question code almost looks like output from a disassembler, hand-rolled into something semi-intelligible.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think Mike deserves this one.  His explication is a lot clearer than mine, *and* he also spotted the fact that the code consumers one too many characters.

Answer (score 1):

The routine is doing a combination of reading in character values and converting them to an integer value in the same operation (to be fast, apparently).  The shifts are aiding in the summation of the values.  The combined shifts equal x10.